How to create an ArrayList filled with generic type objects in Main class?
My program has 5 classes:

Abstract class Car

public abstract class Car {
}


class BMW

public class BMW extends Car implements Comparable<BMW> {
//some logic
}


class Opel

public class Opel extends Car implements Comparable<Opel> {
//some logic
}


class that performs some operations on the classes being compared, extending class Car

public class CarOperations {

    private CarOperations(){
    }

    public static <T extends Car & Comparable<T>> void operation1 (ArrayList<T> array) {
         //some logic
    }
        
}


Main class. My problem is with him.
I want the Main class to have an array of objects of any of the classes extending the Car class. That is, an array that could be filled with either BMW class objects or Opel class objects. Moreover, this array can be fed into the operation1 method of the CarOperations class.

I do the following
public class Main <T extends Car & Comparable<T>>{

    public static <T extends Car & Comparable<T>> void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<T> cars = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Opel(), new Opel()));
}
}

But I see a mistake: "Required type: ArrayList<T>, Provided: ArrayList<Opel>".
I can do this in Main Class:
ArrayList<? extends Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Opel(), new Opel()));

but then when calling a method from a CarOperations class, I see: "Required type: ArrayList<T>  Provided: ArrayList <capture of ? extends CustomClass>".
Please tell me how I can fix this.

That main method doesn't know that T is Opel it might be BMW depending on how the method is called. So it can't be sure that the ArrayList creation is correct.

BTW be aware that <T> from class Main is not the same <T> as method main (neither is really needed)

The generic declaration for operation1 means that the list can only be one type extending Car. If you want both types in the list then don't use generics and just declare the arrays as ArrayList<Car>. It doesn't look like you need to use generics here at all.

I think the main problem here is wrong class hierarchy. If you want to have cars which can support this operation and are comparable, then I would introduce a new interface CarComparable which extends Comparable interface, Specific cars should implement this interface (if you have a limited set of cars which can support this interface and you want let's say only 3 brands, try to use sealed keyword. Then you could store these objects as ArrayList<CarComparable>. Now you should not have any issues.

You can specify the generic type explicitly for ArrayList<T> in the main method.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Car {
}

public class BMW extends Car implements Comparable<BMW> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(BMW other) {
        return 0; // Your comparison logic
    }
}

public class Opel extends Car implements Comparable<Opel> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Opel other) {
        return 0; // Your comparison logic
    }
}

public class CarOperations {

    private CarOperations() {
    }

    public static <T extends Car & Comparable<T>> void operation1(ArrayList<T> array) {
        System.out.println("Performing operation on: " + array.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}

Inside your main method:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(); 
    cars.add(new Opel());
    cars.add(new BMW());

    ArrayList<Opel> opelCars = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BMW> bmwCars = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car instanceof Opel) {
            opelCars.add((Opel) car);
        } else if (car instanceof BMW) {
            bmwCars.add((BMW) car);
        }
    }

    CarOperations.operation1(opelCars); // Pass each type-specific list to operation1
    CarOperations.operation1(bmwCars);
  }
}


Yes. i can this.
But it is highly desirable for me to store both Opel class objects and BMW class objects in one ArrayList.
That is, ideally, I need exactly something like what I'm trying to do.
ArrayList userObjects = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Opel));

Let me explain, the user could specify both objects of the Opel class and objects of the BMW class.
By storing them in different arrays, I will have to describe the forks by passing a specific ArrayList() to the operation method

@Serg check the updated asnwer.

Just because it's desirable doesn't mean it's possible.
